# using Http on angular 2 unit tests

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, http, angular, dependency-injection

I'm using this seed project: https://github.com/juliemr/ng2-test-seed that was recently updated to RC5 of angular.

I want to use the Http component in unit test so I did the following:

In package.json I added to dependencies:

```
"@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.5",
```

In src/test/user-service_test.ts I added:

```
import { HttpModule, Http } from '@angular/http';
```

and modified the beforeEach function to include HttpModule:

```
beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      providers: [LoginService, UserService, HttpModule]
    });
  });
```

Now, as soon as I add the HttpModule in the beforeEach function and try to execute the test I got this error:

```
13 08 2016 09:13:27.609:WARN [web-server]: 404: /base/node_modules/@angular/http
Missing error handler on `socket`.
TypeError: (msg || "").replace is not a function
    at /home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/karma/lib/reporter.js:45:23
    at onBrowserError (/home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/karma/lib/reporters/base.js:58:60)
    at null.<anonymous> (/home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/karma/lib/events.js:13:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    at emit (events.js:172:7)
    at onKarmaError (/home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/karma/lib/browser.js:95:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/karma/lib/events.js:13:22)
    at emitOne (events.js:82:20)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:169:7)
    at Socket.onevent (/home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:335:8)
    at Socket.onpacket (/home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/socket.io/lib/socket.js:295:12)
    at Client.ondecoded (/home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:193:14)
    at Decoder.Emitter.emit (/home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/component-emitter/index.js:134:20)
    at Decoder.add (/home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/socket.io-parser/index.js:247:12)
    at Client.ondata (/home/david/Workspace/ng2-seed/node_modules/socket.io/lib/client.js:175:18)
    at emitOne (events.js:77:13)
```

I'm still not using the Http component in a "it" function, does someone know how to use Http on a unit test on Rc5? I need to reach my server services.

Comment: `HttpModule` is a module, not a provider, it shouldn't be placed in `providers`. Have you tried `imports: [HttpModule], providers: ...` ?

Comment: @estus Your suggestion seems correct, you could add that as the answer and include the necessary import statement as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TestBed.configureTestingModule` expects module definition object as an argument. [According to the manual](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#imports), imported modules are listed as `imports` property, it should be

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  imports: [HttpModule],
  providers: [LoginService, UserService]
});
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but it was also required in karma-test-shim.js to include    '@angular/http': {
      main: 'index.js',
      defaultExtension: 'js'
    }